# Rotate a line on a graph relative to line's center

Tags: geometry, statistics

I am trying to figure out how to rotate a line relative to it's center.

Given two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ and the center of the line $(x_3, y_3)$, how do I rotate the the line 180 degrees?

For example if the line was $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$, the calculated center will be $(1.5,1.5)$ and the rotated point will be $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$.

I am not sure which formula to use to rotate the line by its center, the ones I found rotate the lines based on axes.

Comment: Do you want to rotate it $90^{\circ}$ counterclockwise? Clockwise? Also, you are rotating a line *segment*.

Comment: Rotating a segment 180 degrees about the midpoint just switches around the vertices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(x-x_{1})(y_{2}-y_{1})= (y-y_{1})(x_{2}-x_{1})$$

Is the equation for a line between $(x_{1},y_{1})$ and $(x_{2},y_{2})$

The equation:

$$(x+x_{3}-x_{1})(y_{2}-y_{1})= (y+y_{3}-y_{1})(x_{2}-x_{1})$$

Shifts the line so that $(x_{3},y_{3})$ is on the origin.

An angle which describes the line is given by the arctan(m) where m is the slope. In the case where the line is vertical choose $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Then we rotate by $\theta$ so the new slope is:

$$tan(\theta + arctan(\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}))$$

So we know the new slope, and the point $(x_{3},y_{3})$ must be in the new line so:

$$(x-x_{3})tan(\theta + arctan(\frac{y_{2}-y_{1}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}))=y-y_{3}$$

Using point slope form.

Comment: I'll just add that the center could just as easily be one of the given points since two points determine a line.

Comment: How do I find a specific point on the new line if I have the distance. So I have the middle point, the distance and the new slope, can I calculate?

Comment: There will be exactly 2 points on a line which have a given distance from a given point. It is the intersection of the circle with radius as the given distance and the center as the given point with the line. I should add assuming the given point is on the line.

Answer (score 0):

As comments have indicated, your query details rotating a line (or line segment) $90^\circ$ rather than $180^\circ$.  This is because the slope of the original line (or line segment) is $1$, and the slope of the new line is $-1$.

In order to determine how to rotate the line around the center $(x_0, y_0)$, where $(x,y)$ is any generic point on the line to be rotated, you first have to decide what the slope of the old and new lines are.  The following approach assumes that both slopes are **non-zero and finite**.  Exceptional but obvious adjustments to the algorithm will be needed if either the old or new lines are either horizontal or vertical.

The point $(x,y)$ is a distance $D = +\sqrt{(x - x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2}$ from the point $(x_0, y_0).$  Further, assuming that the slope of the original line is $m$, you have that $\frac{y - y_0}{x - x_0} = m$.

Assume that the new line will have a slope of $n$, and will also pass through the point $(x_0, y_0)$.  Then, you want to find the point $(x_1, y_1)$ that is on the circle of radius $D$ centered at $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $\frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0} = n.$

Two ideas to consider:

- being on the circle of radius $D$ merely signifies that $(x_1, y_1)$ also satisfies the constraint that $D = +\sqrt{(x_1 - x_0)^2 + (y_1 - y_0)^2}$.
- there is a **hidden ambiguity** within this algorithm.  That is, if the point $P_1 = (x_0 + r, y_0 + s)$ satisfies the constraints, then so does the point $P_2 = (x_0 - r, y_0 - s)$.  In such a circumstance, you need to explicitly specify whether $(x,y)$ is rotated to $P_1$ or $P_2$.

Two plausible **distinct** options for generically resolving the *hidden ambiguity* are:

- $(x_1 - x_0) > 0 \iff (x - x_0) > 0.$
- $(y_1 - y_0) > 0 \iff (y - y_0) > 0.$